# Gremlin loop stop condition

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop

I've seen a lot of examples for the tinkerpop 2.x loop step that use it.loops as the stop condition.

```
g.V.in.loop(1){it.loops < 3}
```

What I would prefer is for the loop to continue until its found a vertex type like so:

```
g.V.in.loop(1){it.object.type != "rule"}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Are vertex properties available through the it.object?

I can't use Tinkerpop 3.x repeat until OrientDB releases an update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
g.V.in.loop(1){it.object.type != "rule"}
```

I only changed the V to LowerCase to UpperCase and it works for me

Take a look:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: Thanks but I figured out that the "type" property in OrientDB is actually not a string but and OrientVertexType object so that's why the equality was failing.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by dertermining that it.object.type was not a string  OrientVertexType object which was why the equality check was failing.

Updating to this solved the issue:

```
g.V.in.loop(1){it.object.type.toString() != "rule"}
```